# D3js arcTween error: r is not a function (update fails)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to get a pie chart to update and it works in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/yMVgeX) but when I try to make it larger scale it completely fails.

This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
var d2_data, d2_path, d2_pie, d2_text, d2_arc;
function D2_Update()
{
  d2_data = [d2_employed,d2_student,d2_unemployed,d2_retired];

  d2_path.data(d2_pie(d2_data))
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween(null, d2_arc)); // Redraw the arcs

  d2_text.data(d2_pie(d2_data))
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d2_arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d){return d.data;});
}

function arcTween(a, arc) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}
```

When this update function is called the text on the chart correctly updates--once--and then it fails to actually change the arcs like in the CodePen I linked above. All I get in return is a console error reading `TypeError: r is not a function` coming from my D3js JavaScript file.I am completely confused here because I'm not really sure what I should be doing differently.

Any help is appreciated in understanding my issue. I will also display my code for this graph pie chart:

```
// D2 pie
d2_data = [d2_employed,d2_student,d2_unemployed,d2_retired];
var d2_dataKey = ["Employed","Student","Unemployed","Retired"];

var d2_width = 400,
    d2_height = 400,
    d2_radius = Math.min(d2_width, d2_height) / 2;

d2_arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(d2_radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(d2_radius - 85);

d2_pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d;
    });

var d2_svg = d3.select("#general_d2-graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", d2_width)
    .attr("height", d2_height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "pieChart")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d2_width / 2 + "," + d2_height / 2 + ")");

d2_path = d2_svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(d2_pie(d2_data))
    .enter()
    .append("path");

d2_text = d2_svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(d2_pie(d2_data))
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
      return "translate(" + d2_arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d){return d.data;});

d2_path.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(d.data);
    })
    .attr("d", d2_arc)
    .each(function(d) {
        this._current = d;
    }); // Store the initial angles
```

Thank you.

Comment: `I try to make it larger scale it completely fails`; what does this mean?  What are you expecting this line `.attrTween("d", arcTween(null, d2_arc))` to do?

Comment: I thought it should call the `arcTween` function and send it the value `arc` but I gotta be honest, I don't really understand the ins and outs of that function. In any case, the error persisted even when I commented out those additions and I ended up having to revert to an older copy. I'm working through implementation again at the moment. I want to use the `arcTween` function for multiple pie charts on my web page in order to update them but I'm lost on exactly the right way to go about it.